# How to create Live USB from a running Ubuntu installation

Tags: installation, virtualbox, live-usb, uck

I installed Ubuntu and did some customisations (actually, it's on a VM running inside VirtualBox, however this might not be relevant).

Now I wonder, whether it would be possible to create a Live USB drive with all the customisations that I put in place. What I care about is that when someone actually uses the Live USB to install Ubuntu, he would then get all the changes that I made.

Changes involve:

- Downloading some Git repos from the web,
- Installing a few packages,
- Changing their configuration, e.g. configuring a Tomcat web server.

I came accross UCK (Ubuntu Customisation Kit). It seems it could help me do what I want however it's not ideal. It allows to customise the installation from a console. Unfortunately, there is no way to test things like a webserver installation. Also - in case I screwed something up - I have to redo all the work all over again.

**Questions:**

- Is there a way to create a Live USB from a running Ubuntu installation?
- Is there a way to avoid redoing all the work every time I run Ubuntu Customisation Kit?

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

im sorry, but i am sure that is NOT possible, except if you are currently trying ubuntu.

Comment: If I understand correctly - it's impossible to create a Live USB of a running ubuntu installation. The other option that you mention doesn't work either, AFAIK. That is - customisations you do while working from a thumb drive don't actually persist after the installation is completed.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible.

Using a software called: http://www.remastersys.com/
It takes whatever packages you have but at the same time you can choose to include your settings and personal data too.

You may take a look at the following for different solutions:
http://www.techradar.com/news/software/operating-systems/10-scripts-to-create-your-own-linux-distribution-665247

Warning: Main developers of Remastersys and Ubuntu Builder both recently announced they are abandoning their project and sadly an attempt of a fork was not persistent. You could try them though.
I am in a need of a same solution!